# Can't get a raw link to a product page in a View (Drupal 7,Commerce)

Tags: view, drupal-7

I need to export some information about products of my site for future use in some other cases. I've created a View with all fields which I need to be exported.
Everything good, except `content:link` field. I can't get content link itself. Instead, I've got word "view" but I want something like "http://example.com/myproduct1".
I've switched on the checkboxes "`Output this field as link`" and "`Use absolute path`" in "`Rewrite results`" section settings but nothing has changed. 
I still get "View" instead of a raw URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you exporting nodes or product variants?

For my project for an ecommerce site, [strand of silk](http://strandofsilk.com), I used Content: Path as the type.

But it seems that your view output is being over-written by text. Maybe there is some text in the Rewrite Results?